# Nodejs net does not throw error when trying to connect to a host thats not listening

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to test whether a remote host is listening or not using Node.js `net` module:

```
var net = require('net')
var client = net.connect({port:3000, host:remoteHostIP},function(){

});

client.on('error', function(err){
    console.log("Error: "+err.message);
});
```

I would expect that `net.connect` would throw an error if it can't connect but that's not the case.

Also `client.on('error')` does not throw an error.

How can I check if the connection has been possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code posted in the question works fine:

```
node app.js 
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
```

The issue has been caused by a Virtualbox VM for Docker (running on the developer machine) which had portforwarding configured for port `3000` and grabbed the `net connect` request for `localhost`.

Answer (score 1):

It will throw an error when the connection times out which is about one minute of no data transfer.

`Error: connect ETIMEDOUT <ip>:3000`

Use [client.setTimeout()](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_settimeout_timeout_callback) to fire a callback if there's no activity within the allocated time.